# A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found

Tags: python, telebot, csv, telethon

Решил я значит взять готовый код парсера 2020года, переделать его под себя и закинуть в бота в тг
Решил проверить, будет ли приходить сообщение от бота что не указаны апи ид и апи хеш, сообщение не пришло а пришла ошибка в кмд -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\tgtools\TGPars-main\pars.py", line 28, in <module>
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Необходимо ввести api_id, api_hash и phone.")
  File "C:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1549, in send_message
    apihelper.send_message(
  File "C:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 264, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 162, in _make_request
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 189, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found
```

попробовал через чат гпт решить этот вопрос но он никакой инфы мне не выдал

Сам код -

```
import telebot
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import SessionPasswordNeededError
import sys
import configparser
import csv
import time
import subprocess

# Initialize your Telegram bot token
BOT_TOKEN = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)
chat_id = 'YOUR_CHAT_ID'

cpass = configparser.RawConfigParser()
cpass.read('config.data')

try:
    api_id = cpass['cred']['id']
    api_hash = cpass['cred']['hash']
    phone = cpass['cred']['phone']
    if not api_id or not api_hash:
        raise ValueError(" ID or Hash cannot be empty")
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
except (KeyError, FileNotFoundError, ValueError) as e:
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Необходимо ввести api_id, api_hash и phone.")
    subprocess.run(["python", "setup.py"])
    sys.exit(1)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    code_prompt = '[+] Введите код: '
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, code_prompt)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, verify_code)

def verify_code(message):
    code = message.text

    try:
        client.sign_in(phone, code)
    except SessionPasswordNeededError:
        password_prompt = "[+] Включена двухэтапная верификация. Пожалуйста, введите пароль: "
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, password_prompt)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, verify_password)

def verify_password(message):
    password = message.text

    try:
        client.sign_in(password=password)
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"Ошибка при входе: {str(e)}"
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, error_message)
        return

    # Call the `/pars` function to collect participants from chats
    pars(message.chat.id)

def pars(chat_id):
    chats = []
    last_date = None
    chunk_size = 200
    groups = []

    result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
        offset_date=last_date,
        offset_id=0,
        offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
        limit=chunk_size,
        hash=0
    ))
    chats.extend(result.chats)

    for chat in chats:
        try:
            if chat.megagroup == True:
                groups.append(chat)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            continue

    groups_prompt = '[+] Выберите группы для сбора участников (через запятую):'
    bot.send_message(chat_id, groups_prompt)
    i = 0
    for g in groups:
        group_info = f'[{i}] - {g.title}'
        bot.send_message(chat_id, group_info)
        i += 1

    g_indices_prompt = ''
    while not g_indices_prompt:
        g_indices_prompt = "[+] Введите номера групп(через запятаю если много): "
    bot.send_message(chat_id, g_indices_prompt)
    g_indices = input(g_indices_prompt).split(',')
    selected_groups = [groups[int(index)] for index in g_indices]

    participants_prompt = '[+] Получение участников...'
    bot.send_message(chat_id, participants_prompt)
    time.sleep(1)
    all_participants = []

    for group in selected_groups:
        all_participants.extend(client.get_participants(group, aggressive=True))

    usernames = []

    for user in all_participants:
        if user.username:
            usernames.append(user.username)

    save_prompt = '[+] Сохранение в файл...'
    bot.send_message(chat_id, save_prompt)
    time.sleep(1)

    filename_prompt = "[+] Введите имя файла для сохранения имен пользователей (включая расширение файла): "
    bot.send_message(chat_id, filename_prompt)
    filename = input(filename_prompt)
    with open(filename, "w", encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow(['Username'])
        for username in usernames:
            writer.writerow([username])

    success_prompt = '[+] Имена успешно собраны и сохранены в файле.'
    bot.send_message(chat_id, success_prompt)

    # Send the file to the user
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        bot.send_document(chat_id, file)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['pars'])
def pars_command(message):
    # Call the `pars` function to collect participants from chats
    pars(message.chat.id)
    
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    response = "Извините, я могу обрабатывать только команды /start или /pars."
    bot.reply_to(message, response)

bot.polling()
```